# Highlight changed files in file tree within visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

The Atom editor highlights changed files when they are inside a Git repo like:

[image]

In visual studio code however I am unable to get the same behaviour. Does someone know if this is possible?

Comment: The accepted answer is for icons not modified filename highlights. For modified highlights vote here: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/8561491-tree-view-different-colors-for-added-modified-fil

Comment: See this issue https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/178

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update October 24, 2017**

It turns out the insider version of Visual Studio code now contains git status color in the file tree. The insiders version is available at https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/

[image]

Comment: Apparently voting has closed for the second link, is there a plugin that highlights modified git files?

Comment: this doesnt answers the question

Comment: And doesnot work either. I downloaded insider vscode, but its not working. Its same as vscode, only app icon color is different .. :(

Comment: It's 2019. Any move on this to the non-insiders edition?

Comment: I am not sure how or why that happened, but once I changed the `scm.diffDecorations` setting (to the same value), the colors were suddenly (re-)applied

Answer (score 2):

It is not implemented yet. But the user @karabaja4 made a HACK and posted it in the issue.

here is the HACK and his comment

> I wrote a gulp task that should simplify the installation of the hack (VS Code 1.15 only).
>
> `git clone https://github.com/karabaja4/vscode-explorer-git-status.git
>   cd vscode-explorer-git-status
>   npm install
>   gulp install # as root/administrator`
>
> P.S. Not tested on all platforms yet, would appreciate if someone would try it on OSX.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/178#issuecomment-322045333

Comment: I think that a little bit more explanation is needed here, as this is not working "out-of-the-box" from these lines of commands...