# Is there a way to have modified files (in relation to git) within VSCode to be highlighted within the explorer?

Tags: git, editor, visual-studio-code, explorer

Currently within VSCode if I want to view the modified files in relation to my Git repository I need to open the git tab.
It would be very convenient if the modified files had an indicator beside them (perhaps an icon).
I'm unable to find an extension that does this.

Does anybody know of a way to achieve this?

Comment: I would argue this should be in super user... Also, I think that describing **modified** status for a file means it was modified in relation to something. I don't think that would make other sense rather than subversioning, so the Git tab seems appropriate. Of course, you can make your own extension! :P

Comment: I've updated the question slightly.
There are many git extensions that are used within the application (not just in the git tab).
It would be a nice optional extension.

Good idea, perhaps I will create my own extension! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highlight changed files in file tree within visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36596587/highlight-changed-files-in-file-tree-within-visual-studio-code)