# In VS Code, how can I view a list of files with staged/unstaged changes, where clicking an entry opens a comparison/diff view?

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-code

I am looking for a plugin or feature of Code to see all the changed files and changes as we can see in SourceTree --> File Status feature, I am attaching a screenshot to demonstrate what I want, it is very easy to go over the changed files with this feature without going over all the project tree-view. I have searched plugins and could not see a single plugin doing this, there are very good ones but they show the changes in a file, does not list you all the changes in the project folder. The reason for this is I do not want to leave my IDE for this.

[image]

I am aware of this nice feature [Highlight changed files in file tree within visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36596587/highlight-changed-files-in-file-tree-within-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps Git Lens and the specific part is to look under the `Repositories --> <Name of your repo> --> <x files changed>`? If you click a particular file under that, then you can see the changes which is similar to SourceTree.

I've clicked the `Piece.jsx` file and the editor shows me the diff.

[image: Screenshot]

In addition, if you want to see the diff inline as in your screenshot, you can do it by unchecking this setting in User Settings of Git Lens

[image]

Comment: can you share a screenshot please ?

Comment: I've attached a screenshot to the top-level answer. Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks, this is really very helpful. By the way I am using `Material Icon Theme` , it looks fancier and visualization is better in mine, just fyi.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll check it out!

Comment: It's a shame VSC still doesn't provide a built-in method for this. A sorting mechanism or filter in the version control panel would do the trick. Not having that, Git Lens does provide a solution.

Comment: How do I open the gitlens interface?

Comment: There is a GitHub issue which details the steps to show the icon here: https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/issues/1162.

Answer (score 1):

VS Code has this builtin. It's the Source Control View. In the Activity Bar, its icon looks like [image]/[image]. You can click on that, or use the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)'s `Source Control: Focus on Source Control View` command.

It displays all repositories in the workspace, and for each one, lists a section of files with staged changes, and of files with unstaged changes. Clicking on a file will open a tab highlighting those changes.

In VS Code 1.85, there's even a button to show an overview diff of those changes in one single tab ("multi-diff editor"). See [related release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_85#_multifile-diff-editor) and [related issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/179000).

Documentation for VS Code's Source Control features can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/sourcecontrol/overview).

Answer (score 0):

If you are at your current branch at which you push your code , then simple check the timeline for that particular file.

Answer (score 0):

Within Git Lens, when on your branch. Under Commit -> 'Compare Working Tree with <branch, tag, or ref>', enables you to compare a branch against, lets say, master.
So, when comparing the branch with master, under 'Compare Working Tree with master', against 'files changed' it shows the number of files that have been changed, and has a tree list of files that have been edited in the branch.

Selecting any of the files from the list opens a diff view of the file (from branch) against master